# swipe-able taps in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll

i want to swipe taps with its corresponding tabview's contents. In below code single tap covered full screen width if i swiped to next tap than contain of tabview need to be changed but i only get content changed when clicking on tap or swiping tabview's contents. I will really appreciate if i get help to solve this issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
 runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: MyHomePage(),
    ),
  ),
);
}}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final _kTabPages = <Widget>[
  Center(child: Icon(Icons.cloud, size: 64.0, color: Colors.teal)),
  Center(child: Icon(Icons.alarm, size: 64.0, color: Colors.cyan)),
  Center(child: Icon(Icons.forum, size: 64.0, color: Colors.blue)),
  Center(child: Icon(Icons.forum, size: 64.0, color: Colors.blue)),
  Center(child: Icon(Icons.forum, size: 64.0, color: Colors.blue)),
  Center(child: Icon(Icons.forum, size: 64.0, color: Colors.blue)),
  Center(child: Icon(Icons.forum, size: 64.0, color: Colors.blue)),
  Center(child: Icon(Icons.forum, size: 64.0, color: Colors.blue)),
];
final _kTabs = <Tab>[
  Tab(text: 'Lead-In'),
  Tab(text:'Contacted'),
  Tab(text:'Demo'),
  Tab(text:'Presented'),
  Tab(text:'Proposal'),
  Tab(text:'Discussed'),
  Tab(text:'Closure'),
  Tab(text:'Follow Up'),
];
return DefaultTabController(
  length: _kTabs.length,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('demo tap'),
      actions: <Widget>[           
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
     ),
    body: DefaultTabController(
      length: 8,
      initialIndex: 0,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              height: 60.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: TabBar(
                isScrollable: true,
                labelColor: Colors.teal,
                indicatorColor: Colors.teal,
                indicatorWeight: 2.0,
                labelPadding:  EdgeInsets.only(right: 250.0, left: 40.0),
                indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                tabs: _kTabs,
              )),
          Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child:  TabBarView(
                children: _kTabPages,
              ))
        ],
      ),
    )

  ),
);
}}
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  I made this dartpad to try and understand: https://dartpad.dev/7e93823359d794f8570fef4a07da0c87  I believe what you are asking is that the swipes that you make in the yellow section (from that link) make the green section move as well.  However, when you swipe the green section, it just scrolls the tabs.  I believe that you want a swipe in the green section to be exactly the same as if you had swiped on the yellow section.  Is that true?

Comment: yeah it was my problem. Can u have solution ? it will really help me